# Transpose in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to **PySpark Dataframe** i am following one sample from [this link](https://mapr.com/blog/churn-prediction-pyspark-using-mllib-and-ml-packages/). In this link they are using pandas dataframe wheras i want to achieve the same using Spark Dataframe. I am stuck up on issue where i want to transpose the table i couldn't find any better way to do it. As there are so many columns i find it difficult to implement and understand **Pivot**. Is there any better way to do that ? Can i use pandas in Pyspark with cluster environment ?

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark API `pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix` has transpose function.
if you have a df with columns `id, features`

```
bm_transpose = IndexedRowMatrix(df.rdd.map(lambda x:(x[0],
                  Vectors.dense(x[1])))).toBlockMatrix(2,2).transpose()
```